# Parsing non-consistent XML-objects using Powershell

Tags: xml, parsing, powershell

I'm trying to parse an XML which doesn't consist of uniform attributes. Example

```
<root>
<object>
  <name>Object1</name>
  <valueString>string</valueString>
</object>
<object>
  <name>Object2</name>
  <valueBoolean>true</valueBoolean>
</object>
</root>
```

The number of sub attributes is always the same but sometimes its a boolean and sometimes its a string and the tag name changes accordingly. The issue is not the type itself but, with Powershell, I have to know the tag name beforehand to obtain the value attached to it.

At the moment I'm doing something like this:

```
foreach($item in $items){
  if(!$item.object.valueString){
     $temp = $item.object.valueBoolean
  }
  else{
     $temp = $item.object.valueString
  }
  $properties = @{
      Name = $item.object.Name
      value = $temp
  }
}
```

This works but I would like a more elegant solution + at the moment it's quite rigid and you have to cater for each and every possibility.

Is there a better way ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ChildNodes` property to access child elements by their order:

```powershell
$xml=[xml]@'
<root>
  <object>
    <name>Object1</name>
    <valueString>string</valueString>
  </object>
  <object>
    <name>Object2</name>
    <valueBoolean>true</valueBoolean>
  </object>
</root>
'@
foreach($object in $xml.root.object){
    $value=$object.ChildNodes[1]
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name=$object.Name
        ValueName=$value.Name
        Value=$value.'#text'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't necessarily solve the general problem of weird XML junk, but a helper function to coalesce the different possibilities could make things trimmer. Tested:

```
function value ($parent) {
    :args foreach ($name in $args) {
        $v = $parent.$("value$name")
        if ($v -ne $null) {$v; break args}
    }
}
```

And you use it like `value ($item.object) Boolean String`, assuming all those nodes have the same valueXXX pattern. (If they're always from a fixed set, you can trim the usage down further by hard-coding that set in instead of `$args`. If there's a lot more variation than valueXXX, you'll need to tweak the helper function accordingly.)

Explanation: Uses `$args` to grab all the unnamed arguments, then loops through, building the property accessor on the fly from a string interpolation, and finds the first non-null result, which it then returns. Loop is labeled just to be sure.